# Is there any setting in android for seeing ANR for an app if app UI becomes unresponsive for say 10sec

Tags: android

I would like to know if there is any setting in android to see ANR (Application not responding) popup window within a specified time value.
While simulating ANR for an app, i am seeing this popup (ANR) is coming after 4mins or so; but i want to have android pops up this popup window within 30sec or so; is it possible to do this by doing any setting in android. Can you please answer.

Comment: As far as I know this is part of the android framework itself. I don't know where you want to use this for but this is not a programming related issue. I my opinion when you program an app, you should avoid an ANR anyway.

Comment: Actually i am trying to simulate ANR with test app to check on when ANR popup window is shown when this test app is run; as its taking long time, i wanted to see if there is any way to lessen this time to see the ANR popup window.

Answer (score 0):

- Open **Settings** in device
- Go to **Developer Options**
- Turn on Show all ANR's

Comment: In above settings path, it just tells that ANR popup window to be show for background apps; but does not show on settings to set the time when the ANR popup to be shown.

Comment: In this case, I think that @gi097 is right: it's part of android itself, you can't change it. Usually ANR shows after ~5sec waiting in main thread. Delay of 30sec, which you're mentioned above, may be device-specific. You can try to debug on emulator.